# Cannot get mailboxer gem to work with heroku RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed my rails app onto heroku (with an in-app messaging system with mailboxer), and whenever I try to message someone, it would show me a 500 error. however, when I check my messages, the message DID actually go through.

I tried a variety of things, such as using sidekiq and redis to run this on a separate server in case heroku does not have enough bandwith for this.
But, now the messages are not persisting; it does not show up at all. I think it's stuck in the queue for the sidekiq job.

Here is our github if needed
https://github.com/makafis/thecampusbazaar

Comment: 500 means an error occurred, evidently after the message was sent. Did you check the logs with [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs)? What did you find? Also, can you reproduce the issue in development?

Comment: so before we made sidekiq, it would give us this error
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
in the heroku logs.

development worked fine, it would get to the part in the controller where it would flash a notice "you sent a message" and redirect.

However, on heroku, it would not flash the message and redirect, it will just go straight to the 500 error

Comment: Where is the connection refused error raised? Does mailboxer send emails? Are the emails being sent? My guess is that sidekiq moved the error somewhere else instead of fixing it

Comment: We're not sending emails, we're just using mailboxer as an in-app messaging system. 
On heroku, before sidekiq, messages were being sent, but instead of the flash notice and redirecting, there would just be a 500 error, but people DID actually get each other's messages.
(what we had before sidekiq job)

def create
    @recipient = User.find(params[:user])
    current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])
    flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

Comment: Is that the code where the connection refused error was raised? Can you add it to the question, and indicate the particular line that raised the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Minling on the same project and we figured it out! The problem was that Mailboxer was trying to send emails, which heroku does not directly support. Since we are just using it as a messaging system, in `mailboxer.rb` we uncommented `config.uses_emails = true` and changed the line to `config.uses_emails = false`.  After that it worked!